# 403 forbidden when using cypress to visit globar url

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, cypress, http-status-code-403, http-error

I'm trying to access https://www.oysho.com/es/ website from Mexico, whenever I manually access it on my broswer it works for both https://www.oysho.com/mx/ and https://www.oysho.com/es/

I keep getting the same error and I'm not sure what's the workaround here, this is for a tester interview so I don't have access to the website permission, but it's a global url.

My code for **cypress.config.js** is

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "https://www.oysho.com/es/",
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

My code for **spec.cy.js** is

```
describe('interview exercise', () => {
  it('visit website', () => {
    cy.visit('/', {
      headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'user-agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
      }
  });
  })
})
```

The error I keep getting is this
[image]